# How can I make the web font icomoon (icomoon.ttf) working with Asp.Net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I am a new ASP.NET WebForms developer and I am trying to use one of the font styles provided by my colleague in my ASP.NET WebForms application. The font called: icomoon. I only have a CSS file called icomoonstyle.css as shown below

But an error occur. **See the request's header below:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:52989/Assets/fonts/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.ttf
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

*Kindly note that I am developing this application locally using the localhost on my laptop.*

**Part of the CSS file:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class*="icomoon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icomoon-quote-left:before {
    content: "\e613";
}
```

**So how can I resolve this issue?**

I also tried to add the following configurations to the web.config file and I am still getting the same error:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".woff" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".ttf" allowed="true" />
          <add fileExtension=".woff2" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you have a `icomoon.ttf` (and the other extensions) in your project? Where are those files located in relation to your css file (paths are relative to the css file)?

Answer (score 0):

You say you only have a css file? The 404 error you are receiving would then be due to you not having all the files.

The CSS file you have is referencing a lot of other files.

You need to ask you colleague for his assets/fonts folder that contains the other icomoon files.